# How do I add the Stack Overflow profile icon to my blog?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, flair

How do I add the Stack Overflow profile icon to my blog?

Comment: Send to meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 26):

You get it from here

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are correct if your blog supports embedding HTML. If you can only embed images, you can use this:

[StackImage - Generating Images of Questions and Users [Now with Global Flair!]](https://stackapps.com/questions/847/stackimage-generating-images-of-questions-and-users)

Comment: url of stackimage and stackimage2 doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your own profile - there is a link under it that says `got flair?`. Follow the instructions from that.